# Употребление тире и двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, на месте () поставить двоеточие или тире? 
1) "Он был недоволен. И недовольство это читалось во всем () в его позе, ухмылке, взгляде". 
2) "Стоило ему подойти к ней, коснуться руки, как она переменилась () вздрогнула, покраснела и опустила глаза". 
UPD: склоняюсь, что в первом варианте двоеточие, а во втором - тире.

Comment: Анна, на этом ресурсе обычно не выполняют домашние задания за учащихся. Начните выполнять - мы проверим и поможем. Или хотя бы напишите, применение каких именно правил вызывает у вас затруднения.

Comment: Простите. Это не домашнее задание. В первом предложении я думаю, что надо поставить двоеточие, а во втором - тире. Но я не уверена. Поэтому и хотела узнать, как верно. 1) "Он был недоволен. И недовольство это читалось во всем: в его позе, ухмылке, взгляде". 2) "Стоило ему подойти к ней, коснуться руки, как она переменилась - вздрогнула, покраснела и опустила глаза".

Comment: А что это? Ладно, не суть. Главное, что надо хотя бы начать что-то делать самостоятельно.

Comment: Это мои попытки "творчества", а не д/з. Разумеется, "творчество" читать с сарказмом.) Поняла. В следующий раз буду задавать вопросы, указывая, к какому ответу я сама склоняюсь. И почему.

Comment: А... Тогда надо было написать, что текст оригинальный, не из учебника - и ответа однозначного может и не быть. А так вам Vera ответила, не буду у неё хлеб отбивать.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Это тема обобщающих слов, отнесенных к однородному ряду. В обоих случаях классическим вариантом считается постановка двоеточия после обобщающего слова, но при этом возможна замена двоеточия тире.

При постановке тире однородный ряд приобретает присоединительный характер, а обобщающее слово передает основное содержание. При постановке двоеточия, напротив,  автора переносит основное внимание  на однородный ряд, раскрывающий содержание обобщающего слова.

Поэтому ваше решение мне кажется верным (двоеточие в первом предложении и тире во втором).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, за подробный ответ!